# The Value expression for the textrun ‘Textbox15.Paragraphs[0].TextRuns[0]’ contains an error: [BC30201] Expression expected

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I received this error when I am trying to run a select statement in a text box in SSRS. So, basically, I am trying to return a field which is not in the given dataset. So I have run a subquery which returns the value using the existing dataset as a container.

But I don't know how to represent that return value in the Expression field. Because the expression field returns a value which is within the dataset provided.

I have provided the SQL that I have written.

Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

My intention is to return the "CommentText" value. However, the dataset does not contain any commenttext field, but an EmpID field. So I have created the subquery below that brings up the CommentText from LaborDtlComment table and when it matches with the EmpID in the report dataset it returns the CommentText Value.

```
select [CommentReturnQuery].[LaborDtlComment_CommentText] as [LaborDtlComment_CommentText],
[EmpBasic].[EmpID] as [EmpBasic_EmpID]
   from Erp.EmpBasic as EmpBasic
   inner join  (select [LaborDtlComment].[CommentText] as [LaborDtlComment_CommentText],
[LaborDtl].[EmployeeNum] as [LaborDtl_EmployeeNum]
      from Erp.LaborDtlComment as LaborDtlComment
      inner join Erp.LaborDtl as LaborDtl on LaborDtlComment.Company = LaborDtl.Company
and LaborDtlComment.LaborHedSeq = LaborDtl.LaborHedSeq
and LaborDtlComment.LaborDtlSeq = LaborDtl.LaborDtlSeq)  as CommentReturnQuery
on EmpBasic.EmpID = CommentReturnQuery.LaborDtl_EmployeeNum
```

My aim is to show the CommentText value in a text field. So I will create the

text field and it will contain the SQL that I have written. Can anyone help

me in this case?

Comment: Are you sure the query works correctly in SSMS?  You should be able to simply add `LaborDtlComment_CommentText` to the textbox as usual.  The only way I can see it failing is some issue with the query.

Comment: Hi Steve,
The query runs perfectly. It returns the results that I am expecting. I have run the query in Epicor built in SQL,called BAQ. But I need this query in a report which is exported from Epicor as SSRS (the dataset are fixed). I can only run some limited query using the dataset which are in the exported report. So the dataset are fixed. If I don't have any field within the dataset which I require to show in the report (customization), then I have to write this type of query to bring the field value from another subquery and relate it to the existing dataset to get the field value.

Comment: UPDATE: The field value does not show any error now. However, it directly shows the SQL query instead of the value that is returned by the SQL. Any suggestion is much appreciated. I am very much disappointed as I have to submit this report on this Monday :(

Comment: Well, it's not possible to call a query in a textbox, if that's what you're trying to do.  This might be easier if you could provide some sample data and a general idea of the layout.  All I can really do is speculate without a bit more detail.

Comment: HI @Steve-o169, I have attached 3 photos of the report here.

Comment: HI @Steve-o169, I have attached 3 photos of the report here link: 
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1iFez7vOIye6oSYJNaQeT8pBRBBrve8rQ?usp=sharing

I have made some comments in the image for easier understanding. None of the market datasets contain Comment_text and thats why I have written the subquery.The report does not allow to add anymore dataset as it is exported from Epicor ERP.So the only way I can show the comment is via subquery and linking it to the given dataset in report.I just need to know where to place the subquery and how to return that value in a new comment column

Comment: The only place that you can really add a subquery like that would be to add it into one of your datasets.  I don't really know how your set-up works as I've always just linked directly to SQL Server but you would have to modify the procedure or query for one of your datasets, or create a new dataset based on that query entered as text.

Answer (score 0):

It maybe simpler to use the SSRS function lookup (single paired 1 to 1) or lookupset (multiple 1 to many).[microsoft lookup reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-design/report-builder-functions-lookupset-function?view=sql-server-2017)

You will have to create the query/dataset to return CommentText from LaborDtlComment table with the EmpID

Comment: Hi mate, thanks for your suggestion. My current query actually returns CommentText from LaborDtlComment table with the EmpID. The only issue is I am unsure how to place them in a text field that will show value. For example, I have created a new text field. In the Value expression field, if I put the above query, it shows me the error that I have mentioned.

Regarding the lookup,as I have only one Dataset that doesn't contain commentText, that's why I am unable to use Lookup.

Do you know how to use select statement within a text field to return a value? Thanks in advance